# How to split a camel message body into rows in order to iterate over them in Talend ESB

Tags: esb, talend

So, like the title says, I'm using Talend ESB in order to handle camel messaging. In my case, I'm sending the contents of a file as the message body to the child Talend job. In some scenarios the contents of the file may have 2+ rows. All I need is to be able to iterate over each of those rows independently within the child-job itself.

I guess my question is 2 folded. 1. If possible how do I do this? and 2. is the iteration process better suited at the route level, or the child-job the route calls.

Right now, the files I'm handling are `|` delimited. To handle this, I have the tRouteInput_1 going directly to a tExtractDelimtedFields and use those values to set variables globally, like so.[image: The beginning of child ESB job.]

The problem with this, is it's only reading the first row of the file, and moving on. I need to be able to iterate over each row within the file/camel message.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to split your file on the row delimiter using a `tNormalize`.
In my example, I simulate your `tRouteInput` by using a `tFixedFlowInput` containing the whole file as a single line, with rows separated by `\n`. Then for each resulting row returned by `tNormalize`, extract the fields you want (in `tExtractDelimitedFields`, create the schema corresponding to your row structure):

[image]

And the result:

```
.--------+--------.
|    tLogRow_1    |
|=-------+-------=|
|field1  |field2  |
|=-------+-------=|
|field1.1|field1.2|
|field2.1|field2.2|
|field3.1|field3.2|
'--------+--------'
```

You need to escape "`|`" by using "`\\|`" inside `tExtractDelimitedFields`, as the component accepts regex, and the pipe has special meaning.

As for your 2nd question, I think it's better to do this inside the child job and not the route, as there are dedicated components for this not available in the routing perspective.

Comment: This is perfect!!! I actually stumbled upon this `exact` solution through trial and error late last night. You provided a thorough explanation on all components, so thank you very much!!